# ul li:last-child affects the last li in the second ul

Tags: css, css-selectors

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn73gbqf/)

My problem is that when using the pseudo code `:last-child` I expect the `li` containing `E` to be affected by the style but it's the last `li` in `.subNav` which is affected.

I've tried those(below), but nothing works.

```
nav ul:first-child li:last-child {border: none;padding-right: 0;}
nav ul:not(.subNav) li:last-child {border: none;padding-right: 0;}
```

How to get the main `ul`'s last `li` affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a div after the last li. Therefore, it isn't the last child. You could use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)  to target the last li :

```
nav ul li:last-of-type {border: none;padding-right: 0;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/jn73gbqf/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `div` which is inside `ul`. Adding any tags directly inside ul is not valid.

Place it inside `li` or remove it if not really necessary.

Otherwise your `css` selector is just fine.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li class="B">
            <a href="#">B</a>
            <ul class="subNav">
                <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jn73gbqf/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

That's not the last child, you can use nth-last-child:

```
nav ul > :nth-last-child(2)
```

Or, use last-of-type:

```
nav ul > li:last-of-type
```

---

But I would recommend you to use as @Sowmya answer which is symantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is logically correct, but the problem is that the `li` is not the last child of its parent `ul`, because there's that `div.clear`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li class="B"><a href="#">B</a>
        <ul class="subNav">
        ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

In this case `nav ul li:last-child` doesn't match anything because the `li` is not the last child. You should use `nav ul li:last-of-type` to match the last `li` element.

Note that `ul`s only allow `li` as children, so having a `div` contained in an `ul` is wrong. If you remove that `div.clear` your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo class `:last-child` only triggers if the element is the last child in the parent.

In your case, there is a `div` within your `ul` which is not allowed anyway. Remove it and use a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) of some kind on the parent `ul`.